# Recaptcha click outside modal

Tags: modal-dialog, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am using the new Recaptcha V2 from Google for several links in the same page. My issue is that when I get the modal to prove that I am not a robot by selecting the correct images, if I click outside of it, this recaptcha is not reseted. I was wondering if there is any way to reset the recaptcha when clicking outside of this modal

Thanks

Comment: Any news on that?

Answer (score 0):

Check following code, it works for me

```
        $(document).mouseup(function(e) 
        {
            var challenge = $("iframe[title='recaptcha challenge']");
            if (challenge.length > 0 && !challenge.is(e.target) && challenge.has(e.target).length === 0) 
            {
                alert('Debugging by alerts');
                //challenge.remove();
            }
        });
```